# What's the smartest way to ignore nulls and show a single value for a column that is part of a bigger query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm working with a table that looks something like this:

```
|   |  Name | CaseID | UsrID | DL_NO |   SSN   | Address     | DateSeen   |
|---|:-----:|:------:|:-----:|:-----:|:-------:|-------------|------------|
| 1 | Smith |  AB190 | 88885 |       | 1234567 | 222 Side Rd | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | Smith |  AB186 | 88885 | B0938 |         |             | 10/01/2019 |
| 3 | Smith |  AB170 | 88885 |       | 1234567 | 123 Side Rd | 09/01/2019 |
| 4 | Smith |  AB168 | 88885 | B0938 |         | 123 Road St | 03/05/2019 |
| 5 | Smith |  AB132 | 88885 | B0938 | 1234567 |             | 03/01/2019 |
| 6 | Smith |  AB102 | 88885 | B0938 | 1234567 | 123 Road St | 02/01/2019 |
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly include data that updates/occasionally has missing bits.

What I'd like to see are the most up-to-date, non-null values for each column:

```
|   |  Name | NumOfCases | UsrID | DL_NO |   SSN   | Address     |
|---|:-----:|:----------:|:-----:|:-----:|:-------:|-------------|
| 1 | Smith |      6     | 88885 | B0938 | 1234567 | 222 Side Rd |
```

I was using this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Name, UsrID, COUNT(DISTINCT CaseID) as NumofCases
FROM People
WHERE DateSeen between 01/31/2019 and 10/02/2019
GROUP BY Name, UsrID
ORDER BY DateSeen desc
```

Returns

```
|   |  Name | UsrID | NumofCases |
|---|:-----:|-------|:----------:|
| 1 | Smith | 88885 |      6     |
```

This was working okay until I realized I have a use for the other fields.

When I attempt a similar query with the additional columns, the forced GROUP BY obviously ruins the "NumofCases" count.

Even a CROSS APPLY where I "SELECT TOP 1" requires a group by.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please clarify that you want the latest (by `DateSeen`) non-null value for each of `DL_NO`, `SSN`, `Address` and that `DateSeen` is always populated.

Comment: Sql Server or Sybase? What version?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can help:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Name, UsrID, COUNT(DISTINCT CaseID) as NumofCases,
(select top 1 b.DL_NO FROM People b where a.UsrID = b.UsrID and ltrim(rtrim(b.DL_NO)) <> '' and b.DL_NO is not null order by b.DateSeen desc) as DL_NO,
(select top 1 b.SSN  FROM People b where a.UsrID = b.UsrID and ltrim(rtrim(b.SSN)) <> '' and b.SSN is not null order by b.DateSeen desc) as SSN,
(select top 1 b.Address FROM People b where a.UsrID = b.UsrID and ltrim(rtrim(b.Address)) <> '' and b.Address is not null order by b.DateSeen desc) as Address,
FROM People a
WHERE DateSeen between '01/31/2019' and '10/02/2019'
GROUP BY Name, UsrID
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try below query -

```
SELECT Name
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT CaseID) OVER(PARTITION BY Name)
      ,UsrID
      ,MAX(DL_NO) DL_NO
      ,MAX(SSN) SSN
      ,MAX(Address) Address
      ,MAX(DateSeen) DateSeen
FROM People
WHERE DateSeen BETWEEN 01/31/2019 AND 10/02/2019
GROUP BY Name, UsrID
ORDER BY DateSeen desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the data model, normalizing your tables would make the problem much simpler.  It would also prevent data inconsistencies like the address inconsistency in your example data

```
create table People ( name, usrid, dl_no,ssn, address); --add data types
create table Case (usrid, dateseen, caseid);--add data types

create case_view as
select name,usrid,dl_no,ssn,address,dateseen,caseid
from people p join case c on p.usrid=c.usrid;
```

Then your query is trivial

```
select name,usrid,dl_no,ssn,address,COUNT(DISTINCT CaseID) as NumofCases
from case_view
group by name,usrid,dl_no,ssn,address
```

and you can add date or count filters.